# Quarkus Resteasy reactive multipart stream

Tags: resteasy, quarkus, multipart, reactive

The question: is it possible in Quarkus Resteasy reactive to start process uploading file immediately without waiting until it fully uploaded?

Sample code:

```
class FileUploadForm {
    @RestForm
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    lateinit var title: String

    @RestForm
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    lateinit var description: String

    @RestForm
    lateinit var file: FileUpload
}

@Path("/upload")
class UploadResource {    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    suspend fun upload(form: FileUploadForm): Response {
        val file = form.file.uploadedFile()
        //... do processing only after upload
    }
}
```

What I have found so far:

- for upload we can use only `FileUpload` type (would be nice to have a Vert.x `AsyncFile` or similar, it's an option for streaming download btw)
- there is an interface `org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.multipart.FormDataParser` where you can modify the multipart form processing, but looks like the default implementation is managed by Quarkus and I'm not sure that it will be easy to configure.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to have your `upload` method called before the file upload is complete?

Comment: As far as I know you need to have fully downloaded the file within the tmp before being able to handle the request in your code, at least at the moment, because more parts may come.

Comment: @geoand basically, yes, it would be great to execute processing before saving file to temp directory.

Comment: @JavierToja it makes sense, but we can start process parts immediately as they come and finish processing when receive final HTTP part.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus with RESTEasy Reactive does not support that use case.
I am not even sure that if Vert.x does to be honest.